# Installin Tomcat on Windows 7

Tags: tomcat, installation, setenv

I am looking to install Tomcat. 
So, I unzipped the file, set CATALINA_HOME to the path name I see on the command line (`c:\Users\myName\apache-tomcat-7.0.40` on my machine)
and my *setenv.bat* looks like as follows:

```
set "JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;"
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;"
exit /b 0
```

I also tried

```
set "JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6;"
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07;"
exit /b 0
```

and just

```
set "JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6;"
exit /b 0
```

However, when I invoke *startup.bat*, I keep getting the error that "The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined properly...".

the path name there `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6` is the one on my PATH variable of Windows/System Environment variables. JRE and JDK have been running since months on this machine-- they are installed fine.

Where am I wrong ?

Note: I saw [installing Tomcat 7.0.37; CATALINA_HOME not defined correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525077/installing-tomcat-7-0-37-catalina-home-not-defined-correctly) among many other Tomcat installation Qs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the semi-colon at the end, e.g.:

```
set "JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6"
```