# Java -- settings

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have been using Java on my Windows 7 machine for a long time, without any problems. 
However, the java compiler has stopped working.

The files themselves aren't damaged-- all work under the \bin directory. But the commands `javac` and others 
aren't recognized elsewhere.

This makes think that the path definitions aren't correct. However, they are-- all set correctly. In fact, I've been using Java on this machine as is for months and I haven't changed the path variables or anything else on Java settings.

One thing I did is to install Tomcat and thus APPENDED the path variable for it-- so the Java path definitions are still there as they were. When I invoked Tomcat, the system was asking me whether to "allow this program to make any changes to my computer" in a pop-up window. I set it up on this window so that, when I invoke Tomcat, it won't ask again and run it directly.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't install (or an update has installed) a _JRE_ instead of a JDK?

Comment: Yes. both jdk and jre have been installed and I have been using them for long. I didn't even go to that directory.

Comment: And what does the system path look like, then?

Comment: The only thing I installed is Tomcat yesterday. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948667/installin-tomcat-on-windows-7 how I did it. Today I woke up to this.

Comment: My Path Java variables are these: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07; C:\Program Files\Java\jre6; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;

Answer (score 0):

I think your System and User Variables are mixing. Keep all the variables in system namespace and remove all from user ones.

Comment: How do I do that. Keep in mind that I haven't changed anything of Java for this to happen.

Comment: Something went on during the Tomcat installation. But I haven't done anything suspicious except that pop-up window setting.

Answer (score 0):

Most Windows services -- including those run with the option "Allow service to interact with desktop" in Windows -- do not have access to many of the computer's resources, including the console display. For the same reason that option is provided in Tomcat which does not harms path variable.

To resolve the issue which you are facing you may try this approach. I think that will work:
1. Right click My computer.
2. Go to Advanced System Settings.
3. Click on Environmental Variables.
4. Search for path variable in User Variables and System Variables. Chances are that your path variable is present in both places and it is the reason why conflict is occurring.
5. If there are two occurrences, remove one of the variable either system or user and add it's  value to other one.
For eg. If system's path variable is "c:\jdk1.7\bin;"
and user's path variable is "d:\orable\bin;"
Then concatenate both string delimited by semicolon and set it in system's path variable
so it will look like "c:\jdk1.7\bin;d:\orable\bin;"
and remove the other one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You aren't reading. My path and variables other variables are defined fine. they are overwritten somehow-- still yet to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Restored Windows to the last restore point and worked. Still don't know what went wrong in the settings back in that setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin;%PATH%
java -version
```